# How to generate PDF using jsPDF and canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm tryin to generate an entire html page into pdf using canvas2image, then prepare it for download.
but sadly, That ain't working at all:((
if you have any information of what am I doin wrong, please do share away.
here is my code:

```js
function genPDF() {
  html2canvas(document.body, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {

      var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      var doc = new jsPDF();
      doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 20, 20);
      doc.save('test.pdf');
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<head>
  <title>jsPDF</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>jsPDF Demos</h1>
  <a href="javascript:genPDF()">Download PDF</a>
  <div id="testDiv">
    <h1>Example Header </h1>
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="button" />
    <br><br>
    <img src="test.jpg" width="600" height="400" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @KingStone well it doesn't generatin download link OC, nd in inspect console i'v got Uncaught ReferenceError: Promise is not defined tslib.es6.js:66 :(

Comment: I added my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function genPDF() {

    var dom = document.getElementById('testDiv');
    html2canvas(dom).then(function(canvas) {
        var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 20, 20);
        doc.save('test.pdf');
    });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jsPDF</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>jsPDF Demos</h1>
    <a href="javascript:genPDF()">Download PDF</a>
    <div id="testDiv">
        <h1>Example Header </h1>
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="submit" value="button" />
        <br><br>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zgrsf.png?s=328&g=1" width="600" height="400" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Reference: https://html2canvas.hertzen.com

Comment: Is your demo supposed to do anything?

Comment: Yes, you need create new html file, and you can test, that works well in my side.

Comment: Thanks for respondin so quick, but I've got this error-> Uncaught ReferenceError: Promise is not defined tslib.es6.js:67
nd stil that's not workin for me...

Comment: I tested google chrome, what is your brower?, Do you using angular, or react js?

Comment: I did it with chrome too, I tested ie nd edge but it seems  'Promise' is undefined.... nd sry I'm not usin those frameworks....

Comment: aww, idk what is wrong with mine then, Thanks for helpin btw,I was wonderin if there was any chance to upload ur ".html" doc that I can test that?

Comment: ThanQ btw dear.